# Copiar e Colar Especial com VBA

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho um script VBA que copia uma coluna (de uma planilha Excel) com fórmulas e cola apenas o resultado (Colar Especial).

Porém gostaria de automatizar essa tarefa, exemplo:
Sempre que adicionar alguma informação na coluna "A", os dados da coluna "B" sejam atualizados automaticamente.

Segue um exemplo do código:

```
Public Sub pasteVal()
   Range("A1:A10").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range("B1:B10").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Miguel,

Só um exemplo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If

End Sub
```

Quando uma célula é alterada no Excel, dispara essa sub.

Veja mais em:

[Como executar uma macro quando algumas células são alteradas no Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)

Comment: Valeu Fabioln, ajudou bastante